# SciPy's binned_statistic_2d returning 3d statistic

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am using SciPy's `binned_statistic_2d()` function to determine the binned averages of data in an XArray `Dataset`. My usage is shown below:

```
LTSbins = list(cloudcorrLTSw.LTS.values)[::5]
OMEGAbins = list(cloudcorrLTSw.OMEGA_700.values)[::5]
teststat = binned_statistic_2d(cloudcorrLTSw.LTS, cloudcorrLTSw.OMEGA_700, cloudcorrLTSw.CLD_RHO,
                               statistic=np.nanmean,bins=[LTSbins, OMEGAbins])
```

where `cloudcorrLTSw.LTS`, `cloudcorrLTSw.OMEGA_700`, and `cloudcorrLTSw.CLD_RHO` are 138 entry vectors, the former two being dimensions of the xarray dataset and the latter being a variable in the dataset on LTS-OMEGA_700 space. The LTS, OMEGA_700, and CLD_RHO data are themselves from a timeseries developed from spatial data, and have been transformed into their current state, so there are, as a result, as many CLD_RHO values as there are of the coordinate values, meaning the data is sparse with many NaNs per row and column. This is the reasoning behind using np.nanmean as the statistic instead of the inbuilt mean function.

Per [the SciPy documentation page for this function,](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html) it is intended to return (among other things) an ndarray of shape (nx, ny), where x and y are determined by the `bins` kwarg in the `binned_statistic_2d` function call. What I'm getting, however, is a 138x27x27 (27x27 because the described binning results in 28 values), with the first dimension being completely full of NaNs. As a result, I must pass `teststat.statistic` through `np.nanmean` *again* to remove that surplus dimension, an operation that doesn't take much time but makes me nervous about interfering with the data. It's probably wise of me to interpolate the sparse data so that the plot doesn't look like this,

[image: current plot output]

but that's another question in and of itself. So, before I can solve that, is this the intended output of `binned_statistic_2d()`?

Updated image to follow some3128's suggestion:

[image: second output]

Updated image following some3128's answer using `statistic = 'count'`:

[image]

The data I was using, I had 'forced' to be in LTS-omega space by creating an xarray object using LTS and omega as the coordinates and CLD_RHO as the variable on those axes. By using the original data (pre- making a new dataset), I was able to get *this* image, which seems much more reasonable. I think I can count this as solved.

[image: final-ish image]

Comment: An observation I have is that the x and y axes on the binned graph only span about half the range of the data. It seems a bit suspect. Try setting `bins=10` and plotting the result using `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt; plt.matshow(teststat)`. Does that figure look any more plausible?

Comment: there's more of a sensible result, it's not perfectly along the main diagonal although instead of using the bin values (I coerced it in the first picture with set_xticks) it uses the bin number (0-9). Is that the right behavior? I've included an updated version in the newest edit.

Comment: I think the 0-9 is just the index of the array fed into `matshow()`, but in this case corresponds to the index of the bins as well. You can access the actual locations of the bins in the original units of the axes - I've posted an answer below with some example code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I synthesised some test data (with 50% NaNs in rho) and ran it through the binning function. Results and code below.

Data:

[image]

Output from binning function visualised using a heatmap:

[image]

When I binned the data, I set the statistic to `"count"`. This provides a sanity check on the number of observations in each bracket. The binning function also returns the edge values of the bins, which I've overlaid onto the plot. The colouring reflects the density of the raw data on the scatter plot, so it looks like it's making sense.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)

#Mock data
n_pts = 138
lts1 = np.random.uniform(-0.4, 1, n_pts // 2)
lts2 = np.random.randn(n_pts // 2) * 0.1 - 0.1
lts = np.empty(n_pts)
lts[::2] = lts1
lts[1::2] = lts2

hpa = np.random.uniform(-0.001, 0.0015, n_pts)
#rho has 50% NaNs
rho = np.random.randn(n_pts) + np.where(np.random.uniform(size=n_pts) > 0.5, np.nan, 0)

#View the data
plt.scatter(lts, hpa, c=rho, label='rho')
plt.ylabel('hpa')
plt.xlabel('lts')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
import seaborn as sns
import scipy

#2D binning
#hpa is the "first dimension" (row index), which the function refers to as "x"
#  on the plots, this is actually the y axis
statistic, hpa_edge, lts_edge, binnumber = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(
    hpa, lts, rho, statistic='count', bins=9
)

#Plot
sns.heatmap(statistic, annot=True,
            xticklabels=np.round(lts_edge, 1),
            yticklabels=np.round(hpa_edge * 1e3, 1),
            cmap='plasma')
plt.gca().set_ylabel('hpa * 1e3 bin')
plt.gca().set_xlabel('lts bin')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```

I think it'd be worth seeing if you can run your data through the steps above.

Comment: Axes were not matched, now corrected

Comment: That seems to have duplicated the shape from the `matshow` image, though i should say using bins = 10 on my original binning command gives the same shape. I'm going to try to interpolate the data - I get the feeling the sparseness is the reason the charts look like this. That said, I do think it should look more similar to the scatterplot, in the way yours does.

Comment: I have tried to mimic your data more closely by having 50% NaNs in rho (answer above updated). The functions and binning still seem to work fine. So I am not sure why it is very different with your data. If you are able to share a sample from your data, that can help with replicating the issue.

Comment: So I think it came down, in some way, to how xarray processed the data when I created the dataset `cloudcorrLTSw`; by using the 'original' data (i.e., data which hadn't been forcibly reassigned to the LTS-OMEGA space), I got a much more reasonable heatmap. See the body of my question for details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might be facing an issue either in the way you're utilizing the function or due to the characteristics of your input data. One possible culprit could be related to how you've defined the bins using the LTSbins and OMEGAbins lists. It's worth confirming that these lists accurately represent the bin edges you intend to work with.

Furthermore, it's a good idea to verify that the arrays cloudcorrLTSw.LTS, cloudcorrLTSw.OMEGA_700, and cloudcorrLTSw.CLD_RHO possess the correct shapes and are appropriately aligned with the binning strategy you're attempting to implement. If any of these arrays have unexpected shapes or contain NaN values, they could potentially be causing the unexpected behavior you're seeing in the binned_statistic_2d function. Issues like these can sometimes lead to outcomes that don't quite match your initial expectations.

Comment: The coordinate arrays don't contain any NaNs, but CLD_RHO certainly does. The scatterplot shows a pretty good illustration of my data – values pretty tightly clustered, some coordinates in either direction containing multiple entries of the variable but for the most part being empty.